# How to align Bootstrap 3 Nav Submenu to its parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I included [this](http://www.smartmenus.org) plugin to have my Bootstrap Nav a submenu. My problem is how can I align the submenu to its parent. I need to move it down a little.

[image]

I created a CSS like this:

```
#header-menu-nav .dropdown-menu li ul { margin-top: -27px !important; }
```

And it's working fine. My problem is in the responsive part. It also affected.

Here's my code in simple HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="header-menu-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">New</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Furniture</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lighting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kitchen</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A long sub menu</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Bath</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Interior Goods</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Outlet</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can you help me. Is there a proper way in doing this? Im not really good enough in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
    #header-menu-nav .dropdown-menu li{
     position: relative;
    }
    #header-menu-nav .dropdown-menu li ul{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 100%;
    }
```

and remove the margin-top:-27px;